# Why is a lambda considered an expression (Or: What constitutes an expression in C++)?

Tags: c++, lambda, expression, language-lawyer

[Lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) are considered expressions. According to cppreference an [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) is "a sequence of operators and their operands, that specifies a computation." An expression also has a value category and a type: "The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type [...]" The unique class type is clear to me and I presume it is an prvalue whose evaluation "initializes an object" rather than "computes the value of an operand of a built-in operator" ([Value Categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

The article [Expression (Computer Science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)) on wikipedia says: "[...] an expression is a syntactic entity in a programming language that may be evaluated to determine its value."

I'm still puzzled about what the result of an evaluation of a lambda expression (i.e. its value) is.
For example, consider the following simple unary predicate lambda:

```cpp
[](auto val) { return val % 2 == 0; }
```

What's the value of this expression? Is it an object of the unique class type? Where is the computation that is mentioned in the cppreference definition?

Comment: *Where is the computation that is mentioned in the cppreference definition?* If you can accept that `3` is an expression, in that mathematically it is a constant value, then so is a lambda in a similar way. (The fact that a lambda can be *invoked* is a separate matter.)

Comment: The value is an instance of the unnamed unique type, just as cppreference says. Creating an instance of a type is a computation. (It's not computationally different from, say, the expression `std::string()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the value of this expression? Is it an object of the unique class type?

Yes, exactly that.

> Where is the computation that is mentioned in the cppreference definition?

In the same way that `1` or `std::vector<int>{}` can be said to compute values, so do lambda expressions.

On their own, those all do nothing. The *vast* majority of expressions will either be operands to other expressions (including being arguments to a function call expression), be initialisers for a variable, or have some side-effect when evaluated.

Comment: A lambda expression needs to construct the captures (including running their initializers), so it doesn't necessarily "do nothing".

Comment: _What's the value of this expression? Is it an object of the unique class type?
Yes, exactly that._ A value can't be an object

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the captureless lambda in the question does nothing

Comment: @LanguageLawyer after C++17, yes. Before, no?

Comment: @Caleth Thank you for your answers! Considering Language Lawyer's comment, I'm a bit confused now: Is the object with its data members (if the lambda captures any) the value of the expression, or is it not? If not, what's is the actual value? Does an expression necessarily have a value? And what is the matter with before and after C++17?

Comment: @Ruperrrt after C++17 it isn't an object, it's an unmaterialised temporary. It still has the same value it had.

Answer (score 0):

**value 'category'**, not **value** as a result.

Read this statement carefully: *The lambda expression is a **prvalue** expression of **unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type**, known as **closure type***.

**type:** closure type
**value category:** prvalue

**E.g.**

```
//func has the type of the prvalue expression (closure type)
auto func = [](auto val) { return val % 2 == 0; };

//result has the type of the 'value' returned by function-call operator, 
//here, the type is bool and the value is: (42 % 2 == 0)
auto result = func(42);
```